# Dealing with Transaction isolation level using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring-Boot app and using Spring Boot version 1.5.9.

I have a method for payment transfer that contains a set of DB inserts, and I would like to make it Transactional with locking to avoid double spending. So I need to set the isolation level to Serializable.
And this is what I've done:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void transfer() {
...
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the below exception when calling this method:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1539357851437,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException",
    "message": "JtaTransactionManager does not support custom isolation levels by default - switch 'allowCustomIsolationLevels' to 'true'",
    "path": "app/transfer"
}
```

I'm new to Spring in general and SpringBoot doesn't seem to have an XML configuration that I can override to set allowCustomIsolationLevels to true for the JtaTransactionManager bean. But Instead i should use Java annotation and @Bean definitions and I'm not sure how to achieve my goal with this.

Any help would be apprciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use an XML file for configuration, in your main class that has the `@SprintBootApplication` annotation just add this:

`@ImportResource("classpath:/static/context/name-of-context-file.xml")`

Which will import the XML file from a path where the root is the resources directory in the project.

From what I can tell from [Spring's Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html), you'll want to look into potentially using the DataSourceTransactionManager or using the XML file like I mentioned, since according to that documentation (much like the error message states, but at least gives you the option of setting)

> JTA does not support custom isolation levels.

I know that page I linked is long, but if you just do a find on the page for "custom isolation" it narrows it down to three options, two of which are right next to each other.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so `setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true)` means Spring will support custom isolation levels via Spring JTA over JTA?